# user added to group using web service but no permission

Tags: permissions, web-services

I used the web service _vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?op=AddUserToGroup to add a user to the owner group of a site collection. The user is shown as a member of the group but doesn't have access to the site collection. When I use "check permission" the users isn't shown as a group member. Is there anything more I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the anwer in the nintex community:

The user has to be given as i:0#.w|domain\username and not as domain\username